# How can I use the same imports from a different script?

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have `script1.py` which has

```
from itertools import izip_longest, islice
```

and somewhere in `script1.py`, `islice` is used.

I have another script, `script2.py`, which needs to be automatically executed within `script1.py` because `script1`'s output file is `script2`'s input file. Problem is, `script2` also needs to use the `islice`. Is there a way to use it without importing `islice` again in `script2`?

Comment: Why do you not want to import it twice? As a reader, if I see someone import or use islice from script1, I'll assume that's a different function from the one in itertools. This just makes your code confusing, and introduces an unnecessary dependency on script1 from script2, that there must be that itertools import line.

Comment: Actual imports only happen once. Successive imports do not reload anything, just fetch the reference.

Comment: @MadPhysicist it's because my professor told me to not import the same thing twice. Can you please elaborate on what you mean by not reloading anything so I can tell it to him

Comment: @sneedshelp. Your professor seems to be missing some key information, to put it mildly. I'll post an answer momentarily (or find a duplicate if I can).

Answer (score 1):

What you could do here is import `*` from script1, which would also include all its imports as well. Something like this:

```
# in script2.py
from script1 import *
```

This way you only have to do the imports once. Is this what you mean?

Comment: This is not a very good idea. You may clobber some unexpected names.

Answer (score 1):

The pythonic way to use `islice` in `script2` is to do

```
from itertools import islice
```

The import machinery in Python is pretty smart. Importing a module does not automatically load the module every time. The first step is always to check if the module is already in `sys.modules`. If it is (as it would be in your case), the appropriate existing reference(s) are bound to name(s) in your namespace.

Let's look at a concrete example, with the two modules below:

**mod1.py**

```
from itertools import izip_longest, islice
from mod2 import some_function

# code that uses islice and some_function
```

**mod2.py**

```
from itertools import islice

def some_function():
     # do the thing
```

If you run `mod1`, the following (edited) sequence of events will happen:

1. Create an empty module object and register/cache it under `sys.modules['mod1']` or `sys.modules['__main__']`, depending on how you run the script.
2. Begin executing the code in `mod1.py`.
3. Check if `itertools` is in `sys.modules`: it's not

   1. Do some magic to find, register and load `itertools` into `sys.modules['itertools']`
   2. Add the attributes `izip_longest` and `islice` to your global namespace in the incomplete `mod1`
4. Check if `mod2` is in `sys.modules`: it's not

   1. Do some magic to find `mod2` and create an empty `sys.modules['mod2']`
   2. Begin executing the code in `mod2.py`.
   3. Check if `itertools` is in `sys.modules`: it is
   4. Add the attribute `islice` to your global namespace in the incomplete `mod2`. This is basically equivalent to doing `islice = sys.modules['itertools'].islice` at this point. Nothing gets loaded here.
   5. Execute the `def` statement to create a function object, and add it to the `mod2` global namespace with the name `some_func`.
   6. `mod2` is now fully loaded
5. Execute the remaining code in `mod1`

So as you can see, while you can say that the `itertools` module is technically imported twice, it is only loaded once. The second time, the name `islice` is bound to a local name.

You can read the official documentation about the whole procedure here: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement. This sequence of events has been around, in one implementation or another, since at least version 2.0: https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/import.html. You may also want to read more on how modules work in general here: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html. As a rule, I have found the official docs to be the best teacher of Python outside maybe Stack Overflow.

The other thing to remember is that modules do not share namespaces. Globals within a module are just attributes of that particular module object. However, you could potentially do something like this:

**mod2.py**

```
from itertools import islice

def some_function(): pass
```

**mod1.py**

```
import mod2

#use mod2.some_function and mod2.islice as attributes of mod2
```

This way, you only have one explicit import of `islice`. I would not consider this to be a very pythonic approach though. One of the key principles of Python is "explicit is better than implicit", and readability is more important than succinctness. When you use `mod2.islice`, the implication to the reader is that `mod2` defines a version of the function that is different from the built-in one.

As an aside, consider moving to Python 3.6+ soon. There are many improvements and new features. Python 2.x will not be supported for much longer, and many popular third party libraries such as numpy will be dropping Python 2 support entirely in coming releases.